# Hit & Miss using 4-Way associative cache

Tags: caching, memory-management

Question :

```
Given a computer ,where were made the following memory accesses 

(from left to right) : 

5 ,10 ,2 ,34 ,18 ,4 ,22 ,21 ,11 ,2

* Decide if we have a HIT or MISS when dealing with a 4-way associative mapping ,
  when the total size of the cache is 32 blocks of 2 bytes !

* When you're done , write the final map of the cache
```

My answer :

Size of a set is 4 , hence :

(number of blocks )/(number of ways)=32/4=8

Then we have a cache the has eight cells , from 0 to 7 (**please correct me if I'm wrong !!?**)

Now : 5:(4,5)→5/2=2→2 % 8=2→cell 2→miss

10:(10,11)→10/2=5→5 % 8=5→cell 5→miss

2:(2,3)→2/2=1→1 %8=1→cell 1→miss

34:(34,35)→34/2=17→17 % 8=1→cell 1→miss

18:(18,19)→18/2=9→9 % 8=1→cell 1→miss

4:HIT in cell 2

22:(22,23)→22/2=11→11 % 8=3→cell 3→miss

21:(20,21)→21/2=10→10 % 8=2→cell 2→miss

11:  HIT in cell 5

2:HIT in cell 1

Now , the final map of the cache is :

```
0: empty
1: (2,3) (34,35) (18,19)
2: (4,5) (20,21)
3: (22,23)
4: empty
5: (10,11)
6: empty
7: empty
```

1. Is my answer correct ?
2. Am I wrong with the map of the cache ?

I'd appreciate your help .... my exam is soon :)

Thanks ,

Ron

Answer (score 0):

A simple Python program (ignoring replacements since there are none) says you are correct

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in (5 ,10 ,2 ,34 ,18 ,4 ,22 ,21 ,11 ,2):
    value = item // 2 * 2, item // 2 * 2 + 1
    cell = item // 2 % 8
    if value in d[cell]:
        print "HIT", cell
    else:
        d[cell].append(value)
        print "MISS", cell

for i in range(8):
    print i, d[i]
```

--

```
MISS 2
MISS 5
MISS 1
MISS 1
MISS 1
HIT 2
MISS 3
MISS 2
HIT 5
HIT 1

0 []
1 [(2, 3), (34, 35), (18, 19)]
2 [(4, 5), (20, 21)]
3 [(22, 23)]
4 []
5 [(10, 11)]
6 []
7 []
```